# How to insert a double quote into a chracter array in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, character, double-quotes

I am trying to do this but it fails with the CChar("""). Any ideas I tried CChar("\""). It gives the error "String constants must end with a double quote"

```
Dim arrayWithQuote() As Char = {CChar("a"), CChar("b"), CChar(""")}
```

Comment: Use char literals `{"a"c, "b"c, """"c}` instead of this ugly and inefficient `CChar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an extra double quote to escape it (you don't use `\` to escape a string in vb):

```
Dim arrayWithQuote() As Char = {CChar("a"), CChar("b"), CChar("""")}
```

As Tim Pointed out you should use char literals to do this sort of thing:

```
Dim arrayWithQuote() As Char = {"a"c, "b"c, """"c}
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
Dim arrayWithQuote() As Char = {"a"c, "b"c, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(34)}
```

Comment: Since you answered 15 seconds before Rahul, you get the answered credit. Also you gave two solutions. - Thanks

Comment: Time is already overrated at SO. Always accept the best answer, not the quickest. Only if two answers are equal choose the oldest.

Comment: Agreed - the answer I accepted also did provide two ways of doing it as well and was the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try delimiting the string as:-

```
Dim arrayWithQuote() As Char = {CChar("a"), CChar("b"), CChar("""")}
```